# I need to find a hook I can use on all pages, even on WooCommerce shop pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I have tried these but they ain't working on WooCommerce shop pages:

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'age_verification_disclaimer', 10 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'age_verification_disclaimer', 10 );

function age_verification_disclaimer( $content ) {

    $custom_content = '
    <div class="disclaimer-wrapper">
        <div class="disclaimer-container">
            Are you over 18 years old?<br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <a href="" class="button disclaimer-answer" data-answer="yes">'.__('Yes').'</a>
            <a href="" class="button disclaimer-answer" data-answer="no">'.__('No').'</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    
  $content .= $custom_content;
  return $content;
}
```

Tried to hook it on init, wp_head and wp_footer too...

What I'm trying to do is to show a layer on top of the site, to verify the users age.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load this code in footer and with javascript check the right answer.

Comment: The Javascript is already in place. That was the least of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it, I figured out that the WooCommerce pages ain't got the_content hook when they are selected as shop page. And after changing the function to echo the content and ditching returning $content it worked.